# .trigger('change') on page load to persist jQuery driven reveal of elements

Tags: php, jquery

I have various input elements which control the "hidden" state of various dependent divs.

The type of input varies, and the value which the input must equal (to reveal the div) also varies. I have used php to write javascript (jQuery) depending on these factors, by using the general piece of code:

**php**

```
$remove .=" $('#".$id."').removeClass('hide');";        
$add .="$('#".$id."').addClass('hide');";
```

...

```
$jquery ="              
    $(\"input[name$='$name."']\").change(function(){
        if(this.value == '".$key_val."') {
             ".$remove."
        } else {
             ".$add."
        }
    }).trigger('change');               
";
```

Note: the $remove and $add variables are built using concatenation and loops as there may be several hidden elements which need to be hidden or revealed (hence the .=)

This generally results in a piece of code on page (actual code) such as:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("input[name$='q_32']").change(function(){
        if(this.value == 'Yes') {
              $('#qu_33').removeClass('hide');
        } else {
             $('#qu_33').addClass('hide');
        }
    }).trigger('change');

    $("input[name$='q_32']").change(function(){
        if(this.value == 'No') {
              $('#qu_34').removeClass('hide');
        } else {
             $('#qu_34').addClass('hide');
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

On the page this works well: when the radio button in question (input name q_32) is changed, the corresponding element is hidden or revealed.

The `.trigger('change');` is there because I want the divs to be hidden or revealed **on page load** having set the checked state server side.

The following is the HTML is how the page now loads:

**HTML**

```
<span>Yes</span>
<input type="radio" id="q_32_Yes" value="Yes" name="q_32" checked="">
<span>No</span>
<input type="radio" id="q_32_No" value="No" name="q_32">


<div id="qu_33" class="hide">...</div>
<div id="qu_34" class="">...</div>
```

i.e. the radio button is loading in the checked state for Yes, but the incorrect div is being revealed - so it is triggering, however it seems that the value is being read wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name$='q_32']").change(function () {
        if (this.value == 'Yes') {
            $('#qu_33').removeClass('hide');
        } else {
            $('#qu_33').addClass('hide');
        }
    });

    $("input[name$='q_32']").change(function () {
        if (this.value == 'No') {
            $('#qu_34').removeClass('hide');
        } else {
            $('#qu_34').addClass('hide');
        }
    });

    $("input[name$='q_32']").filter(':checked').change()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kuE9Q/)

a more correct script will be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name$='q_32']").change(function () {
        if (this.value == 'Yes') {
            $('#qu_33').removeClass('hide');
            $('#qu_34').addClass('hide');
        } else {
            $('#qu_33').addClass('hide');
            $('#qu_34').removeClass('hide');
        }
    }).filter(':checked').change();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VZeA7/)

If you have more instances of the same code then [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VZeA7/2/)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about jQuery filter function. This works perfectly.